# Enable http2 in System.Net.WebClient

Tags: .net, http2

Is it possible to enable http2 support in `System.Net.WebClient`?
If so, how does one enable this?

Comment: I don't believe it is implemented yet but it is work in progress. if you are willing to contribute: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx

Comment: .NET 4.6 on Windows 10 might support it.

Comment: @montewhizdoh: the article is about HTTP/2 support in asp.net rather than `System.Net.WebClient`

Comment: @botond.botos you're right, sorry.